# Transfer Transaction Failed

Tags: node, transactions, tezos-client, transfer

hello i m transfer tezos in alphnet. using nodejs sdk of sotez.

here i have request :-

```
await sotez.importKey('ed###PRIVATE_KEY###3r');
sotez.transfer({to: 'tz1PwpmDDgak6AZVhPujQBNjc4k1PsUm5q1D',amount: '1000000',fee: '1278',}).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(function(e){console.log(e)})
```

here i got response :-

https://alphanet.tzscan.io/ooicWu5cMBqSLDSwRD5BAK4mpmm9LMpxEcBhY22qoUHnH2BpWSL

which reveal my address successfully but does not perform transfer operation. how can i solved this any one have any idea ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved By Adding high gasLimit and storageLimit.

```
sotez.transfer({
  to: 'tz1deVJgr3948B4VzH5ER6CAXQ5qB6osAMv4',
  amount: 1000000000,
  fee: 1420,
  gasLimit: 10600,
  storageLimit: 300,
}).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(function(e){console.log(e)})
```